# Loop through all children of an SKNode?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have an SKNode with a number of child SKSpriteNodes. A simplified example:

```
var parentNode = SKNode()
var childNode1 = SKSpriteNode()
var childNode2 = SKSpriteNode()

self.addChild(parentNode)
parentNode.addChild(childNode1)
parentNode.addChild(childNode2)
```

I want to run a `colorizeWithColor` action on all of these children. When I run the action on `parentNode`, there's no effect.

I can't use `enumerateChildNodesWithName` on the parent, because many of its children already have names I'm using.

Is there a way of looping through all children of `parentNode`, in order to run a single action on all of them?

Comment: It turns out the native .children call is unusable in normal performance situations.  You have to just keep your own list.  (As if 2017.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can simply enumerate `parentNode.children`:

```
for child in parentNode.children as! [SKNode] {
    // ...
}
```

If necessary, check each child if it is actually a `SKSpriteNode`:

```
for child in parentNode.children {
    if let spriteNode = child as? SKSpriteNode {
        // ...
    }
}
```

As of **Swift 2 (Xcode 7),** enumeration and optional cast can be combined with to a for-loop with a case-pattern:

```
for case let child as SKSpriteNode in parentNode.children {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## As of 2017..

The code is indeed just

```
for case let child as SKSpriteNode in parentNode.children {
    // ...
}
```

But.

## Performance is incredibly bad: it is not usable.

You will have to **keep your own list.**

Naturally, if you are creating a number of "tanks" or "spaceship" you will naturally keep those in a list anyway. It's the only viable approach if you need to iterate.

I ran some test code like this ...

```
    // try Apple's native .children call...
     
    for case let s as SomeSpriteClass in children { k += 1 }
    let t1 = a.microseconds()
    
    // simply use your own list...
     
    let b = Date()
    for s in spaceships { k += 1 }
    let t2 = b.microseconds()
    
    print("\(t1) \(t2)")
```

it is 3 or 4 times faster, if you just iterate over your own list.

Typical output on an iPad ...

```
939 43
140 33
127 33
117 37
109 30
126 33
127 33
109 29
96 30
96 29
99 30
97 30
97 30
```

(In particular, as you'd expect, the built-in enumeration takes forever the "first" time.)

Given the performance, **in practice you must to keep your own list of sprites** and use that list.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of the children by accessing the parent's `children`-attribute, and then loop over them and run `colorizeWithColor` on them.

```
let children = parentNode.children
for child in children {
    // Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to iterate through a `SCNNode` to look for a custom `SCNNode` subclass that I created. Even though this question is for a SKNNode [@MartinR's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27881012/4833705) answer was the only answer that I could find that put me in the right direction. I had to tweak it but this is what I used:

```
for child in parentNode.childNodes {

    if let myCustomNode = child as? MyCustomNode {
        // ...
    }                        
}
```