# SpriteKit: find all descendants of SKNode of certain class?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sknode

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880935/loop-through-all-children-of-an-sknode) shows how to find all children of a SKNode that belong to a certain class, but what if we want all descendants (e.g., grandchildren) that belong to a certain class?

Is there a native way to do this in SpriteKit, or is the only option to create a recursive form of the solution from the aforementioned question?

The SKNode documentation highlights a search function that lets you find descendants with a certain name, but is there a way to filter descendants by class and not be name? We don't want to assign names to nodes if avoidable.

We're using Swift 3.

Comment: Turn the answer in that question into an extension on SKNode and then add a recursive call into it.

Comment: @davecom yup just wondering if there's a more elegant or native way to do it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What we did was pass a block to the SKNode function that finds nodes by name, and used `*` as the search term to avoid assigning a name to desired nodes.

```
    var descendants = [CustomClass]()
    nodeToSearch.enumerateChildNodes(withName: ".//*") { node, stop in
        if node is CustomClass {
            descendants.append(node as! CustomClass)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add this extension to your project

```
import SpriteKit

extension SKNode {
    func allDescendants<Element: SKNode>(byType type: Element.Type) -> [Element] {
        let currentLevel:[Element] = children.flatMap { $0 as? Element }
        let moreLevels:[Element] = children.reduce([Element]()) { $0 + $1.allDescendants(byType: type) }
        return currentLevel + moreLevels
    }
}
```

Now you can fetch all the descendants of an `SKNode` having a specific type (e.g. `SKSpriteNode`) writing

```
let descendants = node.allDescendants(byType: SKSpriteNode.self)
```

### Example

```
class Enemy: SKSpriteNode { }

let root = SKNode()
let a = Enemy()
let b = SKNode()
let c = SKNode()
let d = Enemy()

root.addChild(a)
root.addChild(b)
a.addChild(c)
a.addChild(d)

let enemies: [Enemy] = root.allDescendants(byType: Enemy.self)

print(enemies.count) // 2
```

Comment: This is lovely and should be the accepted answer :)