# How do I get a Node by its name in SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have multiple sprites with diffrent names, like "H1", "H2", "H3" and so on, how do I code so that all sprites with the name "H2" change their color to red?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SpriteKit: find all descendants of SKNode of certain class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274220/spritekit-find-all-descendants-of-sknode-of-certain-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to create an array of all you sprites, then do something like this.

```
var spriteArray: [sprite] = [sprite1, sprite2, sprite3, sprite4]

for sprite in spriteArray where (sprite.name == "H2" {
    sprite.color = UIColor.red
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I also figured out that you dont need an array just:  for nodes in self.children{if node.name == "sprite", node.removefromparent}